# How to get user typed url from browser using PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission?

Tags: android, browser, accessibilityservice, usagestatsmanager

I want to get the browser url(From all browser that is which browser using their mobile) which is typed by user on their browser. I can get that URL by using AccessibilityService. I just want to know the same how to get the url using PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission in android.

Answer (score 1):

> how to get the url using PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission in android.

`PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` will not give you access to the contents of user interfaces from other apps, such as obtaining the contents of the UI of a Web browser.

> I can get that URL by using AccessibilityService

That depends entirely on the implementation of the Web browser.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, is it possible or any other way  to get URL which is opened in browser other than AccessibilityService.

Comment: @karthik: I sure hope not, for privacy and security reasons.